# Парсинг xml в php

Tags: php, html, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Пытаюсь спарсить xml, но походу как-то не так дела, подскажите, пожалуйста
Вот так выглядит xml файл (его часть)

```
<weatherdata>
<forecast>
<tabular>
<time from="2020-04-18T20:00:00" to="2020-04-19T00:00:00" period="3">
<symbol number="3" numberEx="3" name="Partly cloudy" var="03d"/>
<precipitation value="0"/>
<windDirection deg="297.8" code="WNW" name="West-northwest"/>
<windSpeed mps="5.5" name="Moderate breeze"/>
<temperature unit="celsius" value="5"/>
<pressure unit="hPa" value="1014.7"/>
</time>
<time from="2020-04-19T00:00:00" to="2020-04-19T06:00:00" period="0">
<symbol number="3" numberEx="3" name="Partly cloudy" var="03n"/>
<precipitation value="0"/>
<windDirection deg="280.1" code="W" name="West"/>
<windSpeed mps="3.4" name="Gentle breeze"/>
<temperature unit="celsius" value="1"/>
<pressure unit="hPa" value="1013.9"/>
</time>
...
</weatherdata>
```

Я хочу вытянуть из этих классов time значения (а точнее, я хочу вытянуть именно те значения, в которых моя переменная совпадает с временем в xml), но у меня считываются значения только с первой части класса (или как это правильно называется)
Прилагаю свой код (точнее часть кода, где я пытаюсь это сделать)
Можно я ошиблась где-то в синтаксисе, подскажите, пожалуйста!!)
Код:

```
$src = file_get_contents('https://www.yr.no/place/'. $_GET['city'] .'/forecast.xml');
    $data = new SimpleXMLElement($src);
    $str = $data->forecast->tabular->time;
    foreach ($data as $str) {
    if(strtotime($str["from"]) >= strtotime($_GET['date']) && strtotime($_GET['date']) <= strtotime($str['to'])){
        $forecast["Temperature:"] = (string) $str->temperature["value"];
        $forecast["Precipitation:"] = (string) $str->precipitation["value"];
        $windDirection = $str->windDirection["name"];
        $forecast["Wind:"] = (string) $str->windSpeed["mps"] . " m/s from $windDirection";

        $date = date ("d.m.y H:i", strtotime($_GET['date']));
        $city = $data->location->name;
        $result = "OK";
        //break;
        }
        else  {
            $result = "ERROR";
            $error_message = "Not found";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `foreach ($data->forecast->tabular->time as $str) {`

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!)

Comment: SimpleXMLElement  - сдохнет если файл будет большим